# Tab Bar with popup buttons iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to have this type of bar at the bottom of the application and whenever a button is clicked new buttons should popup, which one of them when clicked should take me to its connected view

[image]

Comment: You'll probably want to customize a `UIToolBar` for that instead of `UITabBar`.

Comment: I would advise not to do this. iOS users are used to the familiar tab bar functionality. 

Your design idea is very attractive, but it comes at a cost. This will make it more difficult to use, not easier.

Comment: so any example/tutorial to achieve this design or like this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use Popup as control, I'll recommend you to use it like a notification as this is not Apple way of showing controls.

[Here is a nice link from boctor iDev recipes.](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomTabBarNotification)
You can find here custom `UITabBar` as well **Notification**

Comment: notifications are different then buttons view, buttons will be popped  up on clicking/tapping them

Comment: But you can customize it as you want, you can place buttons as well on that notification and capture the tap event of TabBar button press (which also discussed in that) and show the notification.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to try customizing UITabbar. This will go against the normal behavior of UITabbar and Apple may reject your app for tampering with normal behavior.

You can try having a UIView with a set of buttons in them and bring the similar functionality as in your image.

Comment: thanx Krishnan, can you please refer me to any tutorial/example for the solution u have asked me to implement, also if there is any tutorial related to customizing UITABBAR like what i need then please tell me, thanx